# Undefined reference to symbol that clearly exists in the library

Tags: linker, g++, arm

I've built TinyXML as a static library: libxmltiny.a

A simple test program:

```
#include <tinyxml/tinyxml.h>
void main()
{
    TiXmlDocument doc;
    doc.Parse("");
}
```

Both are compiled with the same g++ compiler which is:
`arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++ 4.6.2`

If I delete the library file, the linker reports that it can't find the file, so we know it finds the file (and we know the objdump below is on the same file).

The (first of several) friendly error is:

> test.cpp:(.text.startup+0x58): undefined reference to
>   TiXmlDocument::TiXmlDocument()

If I suppress the demangling with `-Xlinker --demangle=none`:

> test.cpp:(.text.startup+0x58): undefined reference to
>   _ZN13TiXmlDocumentC1Ev

Dumping the library file like this:

> $ objdump -t libtinyxml.a | grep _ZN13TiXmlDocumentC1Ev

Produces:

> 00002810 g     F .text    000000ac _ZN13TiXmlDocumentC1Ev

So the symbol clearly exists in the library file!

Some googling suggested that I change library order, but it's the only library linked to (other than the runtime library of course).

I've built and linked this library for another project which was a powerpc version of g++.

I have no more guesses. What might I be missing here?

Comment: Could you show your compilation line?

Comment: @Constantius Thanks for expressing interest. I've moved on from this and deleted all the work I did getting BuildRoot to produce the library and the test program. I've added the source files directly to my project. While not ideal, it's good enough for this particular embedded system. I needed to close that work item.